# Error in colnames <-`(`*tmp*`... attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions

Tags: r

I am using the function `predict` to predict for new variables. When I feed the new variables (as a data frame with column names) to the `predict` function, I get the following error:

```
predict(modelX, newvariables)
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("model1", "model2", "model3",  : 
attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

While the `modelX` works for training purposes it fails in `predict`. In order to investigate I would like to know the meaning of the error message in the context of the `predict(modelX,new variables)`. I am only feeding the new predicting variables with the objective to predict the response.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `str(newvariables)`? In general, a reproducible example with complete code would also help.

Comment: The `predict` function can be specific to different types of models. What type of model is `modelX`? (What did you use to create it?) Can you give code to create `modelX` and `newdata` so that this is reproducible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the same error while using the DESeq R package:

> "> cds <- newCountDataSetFromHTSeqCount(sampleTable=cdsTable,
>   directory="/") Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = 237680:237684) :
>   attempt to set colnames on object with less than two dimensions"

In this case the problem was that in the files I was trying to read from there was an unexpected first line with empty first column and "0" in the second column. All files were tab-separated with two columns. As soon as I deleted the top incomplete line with "0" in it, the error disappeared and the command executed properly. I suspect that your error may have similar cause.